# Quartz scheduler not scheduling/firing the jobs

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I try to schedule a quartz scheduler with spring-4.3.27 and quartz-2.3.2 with xml based configuration, Jobs are not getting fired.

Earlier its working quartz-2.1.1 and quartz-all-2.1.1, Now I migrated to quartz-2.3.2 (Quratz-all-2.3.2 which is not available), But the jobs are not getting triggered.

my Quartz Scheduler Configuration like,

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<!-- enable this for websphere -->
<bean name="workManagerTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" />
</bean>

<bean name="quartzScheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="workManagerTaskExecutor" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="nonTransactionalDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> -->
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <util:properties location="classpath:/quartz.properties" />
    </property>
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="Job1" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="messageExchangeLogDAO" value-ref="MessageExchangeLogDAO" />
            <entry key="outboundMessageSender" value-ref="outboundMessageSender" />
            <entry key="marshaller" value-ref="marshaller" />
            <entry key="reportService" value-ref="reportService" />
            <entry key="userDao" value-ref="UserDAO" />
            <entry key="jobService" value-ref="jobService" />
            <entry key="purchaseOrderDAO" value-ref="PurchaseOrderDAO" />
            <entry key="dbConfig" value-ref="databaseConfiguration" />
            <entry key="purchaseOrderService" value-ref="purchaseOrderService" />
            <entry key="userRoleDAO" value-ref="userRoleDAO" />
            <entry key="mailService" value-ref="mailService" />
            <entry key="buyerNotificationService" value-ref="buyerNotificationService" />
            <entry key="supplierNotificationService" value-ref="supplierNotificationService" />
            <entry key="adminNotificationService" value-ref="adminNotificationService" />
            <entry key="messageService" value-ref="messageService" />
            <entry key="messageProcessor" value-ref="messageProcessor" />
            <entry key="em" value-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
            <entry key="invoiceService" value-ref="invoiceService" />
            <entry key="approvedInvoiceDAO" value-ref="ApprovedInvoiceDAO" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="jobTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="job1" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="300000" />
</bean>

<bean name="job1"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.jobs.scheduleJob" />
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="quartzSchedulerPointcut"
        expression="execution(* org.quartz.Scheduler.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="quartzSchedulerAdvice"
        pointcut-ref="quartzSchedulerPointcut" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="quartzSchedulerAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="set*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="insert*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="schedule*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="pause*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="resume*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="run*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="toggle*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="clone*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Quartz.properies:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = TSPScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO 
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=1000
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 10000
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL = SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME  =  ? FOR UPDATE
org.quartz.jobStore.dontSetAutoCommitFalse = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class  =  org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount  =  15
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority  =  15
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered  =  true
```

Logs:

```
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean startScheduler Starting Quartz Scheduler now
org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor finishRegistration **No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing**
```

After that No error and nothing is getting printed in the Logs, at the same time jobs also not getting fired.

In the QUARTZ_TRIGGERS table next_fire_time alone getting updated based fire interval.

Note: The same configuration working fine with quartz-2.1.1 and quartz-all-2.1.1, Not working with quartz-2.3.2

anyone guide me where I did mistake? what I need to do here to resolve this scheduling issue?

Answer (score 0):

**sched_time** column is missing in **qrtz_fired_triggers** table. After adding that column its started firing.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of differences between the tables from 1.x to 2.x. We recently migrated from 1.x and created all tables before deploying the application.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30843162)